# Trying to create Thumb from Video returns null for valid video file

Tags: android, video

Here I am trying to create thumb from video file. I selected video file from my App XYZVideos/ folder using gallery media selection intent.

Videos are already recorded by me and stored in this folder XYZVideos/.

If I am trying to do same thing by picking videos from other folders like camera it's working fine(i.e. creating thumb successfully).

I am using below code snippet to create thumb from media uri i received from intent:

```
String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);

ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail( filePath, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

Is any buddy come across this thing before. Please Help me...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code its solve for me:-

```
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj1 = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor1 = managedQuery(contentUri, proj1, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor1.moveToFirst();
        return cursor1.getString(column_index);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I figured out that I was calling new File(filePath); before passing that files uri to createVideoThumbnail(). BTW I used the same get getPathFromURI() method ...